# Is it possible to prevent submit button from refreshing page? (Angular 6, TypeScript)

Tags: angular, forms

Is it possible somehow to prevent submit from refreshing the page? 
Instead to pop up a modal and after confirming the modal route to another page.

```
<from (submit)="onSubmit(passData)" #form="ngForm">
  <input type="text" name="id" ngModel matInput #idInput="ngModel" required>
 <button type="submit" > Submit </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong attribute:

```
// change this
<form (submit)="onSubmit(passData)" #form="ngForm">
// to this
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(passData)" #form="ngForm">
```

Check [the docs on angular form submission](https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit). This attribute automatically prevents the default browseer behavior, which is to refresh or redirect.

Comment: For others also having this issue, make sure you are importing the form module as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ngSubmit event instead of the native submit event.